# I got data from the server but the array length would be undefined

Tags: angular

I use the following code.

```
export class AppComponent {

    id:string;
    url:string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";
    title:string;
    found:boolean;

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {}
    //https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

    onNameKeyUp(event:any) {
        this.id = event.target.value;
        this.found = false;
    }

    getProfile() {
        console.log("getProfile gestartet");
        var newurl = this.url.concat(this.id);
        //var newurl = this.url;

        this.httpClient.get(newurl)
            .subscribe(
                (data:any[]) => {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.length);
                    if(data.length) {
                        this.title = data[0].title;
                        this.found = true;
                    } else {
                        console.log("No data.length exist: " + newurl);
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

The output in the console is this:

[image]

I got everytime a data-array, but I cant get the length of this array. Where is my mistake? Is this all depending from async?

For me seems so, that the data are available and i can print them, but it is not a array. Is this possible?

Comment: `data` isn't an array, but an object.

Comment: Mhm, interessting. So I will search for the Object. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an array, [its an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_overview). Objects don't have a built in length property. If you define the length of an object as the length of the array of its [enumerable keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then you can do

```
Object.keys(data).length
```